# How can I protect hex code against copying?

Tags: hex, copy-protection

I want to protect my hex code to just run one electronic circuit. 
So I want protect my hexadecimal code against copying.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to run just once, you should destroy your own code when it  ran one circuit.

```
WHEN finished
  copy ptr loc_memory_start, 0000 
  ;comment: fill in zeros at the start of program.
END
```